# Docker compose error : build contains unsupported option: 'shm_size'

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to use the `shm_size` option when building a docker image using `docker compose`. My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: 'db'
      shm_size: '6gb'
```

When I run this I see the error:

`services.db.build contains unsupported option: 'shm_size'`

Does anyone know why this isn't supported?

Running docker app on MacOS with these versions:

`Engine: 18.03.1-ce`
`Compose: 1.21.1`
`Machine: 0.14.0`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The shm_size option was added in 3.5 - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#shm_size

Therefore the fix here was to specify the minor version for the compose file of at least 3.5:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: 'db'
      shm_size: '6gb'
```